# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild

I'm getting an error when packaging the application to an s3 bucket, I'm executing this line with codepipeline and aws code build:

```
aws cloudformation package --template-file serverless.template --s3-bucket dev-btnext-1 
                               --output-template-file NewSamTemplate.yaml
```

That command is specified on the buildspec.yml

Comment: Check if you specified the permissions `"s3:GetBucket*", "s3:PutBucket*" and "s3:ListBucket*"` for your IAM Role / User.

Answer (score 3):

Your bucket do not accept any object which is not encrypted so while packaging use encrytion key to encrypt data before storing like
 `aws cloudformation package --template-file serverless.template --kms-key-id arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:***********:key/d91b925c-8a3b-400c-ae49-******** --s3-bucket dev-btnext-1 --output-template-file NewSamTemplate.yaml`

use Your own KMS key ,you will find Encryption keys for S3 in IAM Encryption keys section.

And also check that your CodeBuild have put access to s3 if not follow below step

1.Go to the IAM Management Console.

2.Choose Roles.

3.Open the service role that was generated for your project, typically
    code-build-project-name-service-role.

4.Under the Permissions tab, choose Add inline policy.

5.In service, choose Choose a service.

6.In Select a service below, choose S3.

7.In Actions, choose Select actions.

8.Expand Write under Access level groups and then choose PutObject.

9.Choose Resources and then choose the Any checkbox.

10.Choose Review policy.

11.Enter a Name* and then choose Create policy. Then return to the pipeline you 
 created in the previous section.

[Building a Pipeline for Your Serverless Application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/build-pipeline.html)

Comment: I doubted this when I read it, then checked the bucket policy on the default CodePipeline bucket. It does indeed require encryption.